# Find the minimum positive value that $(f(x)-g(x)+3)$ may attain.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, contest-math

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be two non-constant differentiable functions. If $f'(x)-g'(x)=g'(x)(f(x))^2-f'(x)(g(x))^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and $f(1)=1, g(1)=\frac13$ and if there is no $x$ for which $f(x)=-2$ or $g(x)=2$ then find the minimum positive value that $(f(x)-g(x)+3)$ may attain.

**My Attempt:**

$f'(x)(1+(g(x)^2)=g'(x)(1+(f(x))^2)$

$\frac{f'(x)}{1+(f(x))^2}=\frac{g'(x)}{1+(g(x))^2}$

$\big[\arctan(f(x))\big]_1^x=\big[\arctan(g(x))\big]_1^x$

$\arctan(f(x))-\arctan1=\arctan(g(x))-\arctan\frac13$

$\arctan(f(x))-\arctan(g(x))=\arctan1-\arctan\frac13=\arctan\frac12$

Not sure what to do next.

Perhaps the answer is $2√5-1$.

Comment: Following your last step, it seems the question can be re-phrased as
> Find the minimum positive value that $(\tan \alpha - \tan \beta +3)$ may attain given $\alpha - \beta = \arctan\frac12$.

Also, $\tan \alpha - \tan \beta = \tan(\alpha - \beta) (1 + \tan \alpha \tan \beta) = \frac12(1 + \tan \alpha \tan \beta)$. Maybe this helps? I'm also curious about why 
>there is no $x$ for which $f(x)=-2$ or $g(x)=2$

is needed. I don't immediately see what the problem is if they could attain those values.

Comment: @TonyMathew my guess was maybe with $-2$ and $2$, the denominator of tan was becoming zero. But couldn't see that in the steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made great progress. Using the [Arctangent addition formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Arctangent_addition_formula), along with your result of $\arctan(f(x)) - \arctan(g(x)) = \arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$, we get that

$$\arctan\left(\frac{f(x) - g(x)}{1 + f(x)g(x)}\right) = \arctan\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

The arguments are congruent modulo $\pi$ so, for some fixed integer $n$, we have

$$\frac{f(x) - g(x)}{1 + f(x)g(x)} = n\pi + \frac{1}{2}$$

From $f(1) = 1$ and $g(1) = \frac{1}{3}$, we get $\frac{f(x) - g(x)}{1 + f(x)g(x)} = \frac{1}{2}$, so $n = 0$. Thus,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{1+f(x)g(x)} &= \frac{1}{2} \\
2f(x) - 2g(x) & = 1 + f(x)g(x) \\
-f(x)g(x) + 2f(x) - 2g(x) - 1 &= 0 \\
-f(x)g(x) + 2f(x) - 2g(x) + 4 - 4 - 1 & = 0 \\
(f(x) + 2)(-g(x) + 2) & = 5
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Note that, with $f(1) = 1$ and $g(1) = \frac{1}{3}$, both of the LHS factors are positive. Also, they remain positive since $f(x) \neq -2$ and $g(x) \neq 2$ (this is likely why that restriction is given since, otherwise, the LHS becomes $0$). Thus, by the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_Inequality), we get

$$\frac{(f(x) + 2) + (-g(x) + 2)}{2} \ge \sqrt{5} \;\;\to\;\; f(x) - g(x) + 3 \ge 2\sqrt{5} - 1$$

This shows the minimum positive value that may be obtained is $2\sqrt{5} - 1$, as you suggested, with this occurring when $f(x) + 2 = -g(x) + 2 = \sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Thankyou. One doubt: why are we saying $(2+f(x))$ and $(2-g(x))$ are positive?

Comment: @aarbee You're welcome. I stated both $f(x) + 2$ and $-g(x) + 2$ start, and remain, positive since the AM-GM inequality *only* applies to non-negative values.

Comment: Got it now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In what follows, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ will be written as $f$ and $g$ respectively.

Note that

$$\tan^{-1} f  =  \tan^{-1} g + \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) $$
$$\implies f  = \frac{g+ \frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{g}{2}} $$
$$\implies f-g+3 = \frac{2g+1}{2-g}-g+3 $$
$$\implies f-g+3 = \frac{g^2-3g+7}{2-g}$$

Let $k=f-g+3$, then $k = \frac{g^2-3g+7}{2-g}$.

Therefore $k$ is a rational function of $g$.

The graph of $k = \frac{g^2-3g+7}{2-g}$ is plotted as below and the minumum can be found by standard differentiation method.

[image]

Alternatively, we may work as follows:

$$k = \frac{g^2-3g+7}{2-g}$$
$$\implies g^2-3g+7=2k-kg$$
$$\implies g^2+(k-3)g+(7-2k)=0$$

Since $g$ is always real, the discriminant of the above quadratic equation is non-negative.

$$(k-3)^2-4(7-2k) \geq 0$$
$$k^2+2k-19 \geq 0$$
$$(k+1)^2 \geq 20$$
$$k+1 \leq -2 \sqrt 5  \; \; \mathrm{or} \; \; k+1 \geq 2 \sqrt 5$$
$$k \leq -2\sqrt 5 -1  \; \; \mathrm{or} \; \; k \geq 2 \sqrt 5 - 1$$

Hence the minimum value of $k=f-g+3$ is $2 \sqrt 5 - 1$.

Comment: Wonderful approach. Thanks.

Comment: In the second last step, at one place, it should be $-2√5$

Comment: @aarbee Thank you. Answer amended.